# How to mimick SSL when developing locally in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, localhost

I have a asp.net mvc application.

Some pages require SSL, is there a way to mimick ssl locally through cassini or IIS 7?

**Edit**
So I followed the directions for the answer below that linked to ScottGu's blog post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create self-signed SSL certificates on IIS 7. Here is the link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> start --> (IIS) Manager --> Select Server --> Server Certificates:

If you already have an SSL Certificate, you can export your Certificate and jump to step 2.
If you do not have a certificate, you will need to create one in step 1.

1.)
Run the following 4 commands from an elevated Command Prompt:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64
makecert -r -n "CN=localhost" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -sv localhost.pvk localhost.cer
cert2spc localhost.cer localhost.spc
pvk2pfx -pvk localhost.pvk -spc localhost.spc -pfx localhost.pfx
```

copy files from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\localhost.cer 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\localhost.pfx
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\localhost.pvk
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\localhost.spc
```

to a folder of your choice

2.)

> start --> run --> mmc.exe certmgr.msc
>   Trusted Root Certification Authorities --> Right-Click Certificates --> All Tasks --> Import
>   Navigate to your Certificate and import it

3.)

> start --> (IIS) Manager --> Select Server --> Select Website --> Bindings
>   Add a binding for https and point it to your certificate.

Test by opening Internet Explorer and navigating to your localhost site with https in IE.

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 supports SSL, but I don't think Cassini does at all. When I've really needed SSL locally, I use [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) as a proxy. Whether that works for you or not depends on why you need SSL (with stunnel, your client webbrowser will think it's HTTPS but ASP.NET/Cassini won't).